# How to replace colon with equal sign within JSON data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am able to get the following JSON as an output after running a chef recipe

```
listener "tcp" {
  "tls_disable": 1,
  "address": "xx.xxx.xx.xx:8200"
}
```

However, I want the chef recipe output in the following format:

```
listener "tcp" {
  tls_disable = 1,
  address = "xx.xxx.xx.xx:8200"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to convert it ruby hash? JSON.parse(string_representing_json,:symbolize_names => true)

Comment: Where are you getting that output from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a regular expression. If your JSON response is in a variable called `chef_output`, you can use this:

```
formatted_output = chef_output.gsub(/\"([^\"]+)\":/, '\1 =')
```

Comment: can you please let me know how can I also get rid of commas. the output should look like  listener    "tcp" {
  tls_disable = 1
  address = "xx.xxx.xx.xx:8200"
}     @taglia

Comment: To avoid complicating the regular expression, you can just do that sequentially: `formatted_output = chef_output.gsub(/\"([^\"]+)\":/, '\1 =').delete(',$')` (The `$` sign limits this to the commas at the end of line).